# XSLT: Get the value of an attribute created dynamically

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm new to XSLT and I'm trying to grab the content of an attribute I've just created.

I have some XML, like the following:

```
<subpara id="subpara">
    <title>I am some heavy title</title>
        <para id="para">Here is some dummy text for a dummy para.</para>
            <table id="t01" tocentry="1">
            ...
```

in XSLT, I do:

```
<xsl:template match="subpara/title">
    <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:text>title</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="addChangeClasses"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:attribute name="data-numbering">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="numbering"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        # HERE I'D LIKE TO HAVE THE CONTENT OF THE ATTRIBUTE I JUST CREATED
        <xsl:value-of select"@data-numbering"/>  

        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

My intent is to create that output:

```
<div class="title" data-numbering="1.1">1.1 - I am some heavy title</div>
```

So I'm creating an attribute **data-numbering**, but I'd like to display its content.
Obviously, doing `<xsl:value-of select="@data-numbering"/>` is not the proper way.

Anyone can help me, please ? Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing what your Template returns I'm only taking a best guess here :

```
<xsl:variable name="d_numb">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="numbering"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:attribute name="data-numbering" select="$d_numb"/>

<xsl:value-of select="$d_numb"/>
```

So store whatever value is returned by the template in a variable. Then use this variable to populate the attribute and output the value.

Comment: Yes @Sebastien! That works! I just used <xsl:attribute name='data-numbering'/> Thanks!